# how to create auto-increment field for multiple collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

i am new to NOSQL(mongo db),i am having a specific question, if i want to create multiple auto incremented field in multiple collections,do i need to create counter collection for each an every collection or is there any alternative way and how is it possible?

Comment: Why you can't use an ObjectID? Can you provide more details about your problem which you are trying to solve?

Comment: Thank's for giving me the response @Neodan. suppose i am having three collections .   Collection A :- {"aId" : 0 , "data" : "A"}, {"aId" : 1 , "data" : "B"}
Collection B :- {"bId" : 0 , "data" : "A"}, {"bId" : 1 , "data" : "B"}
Collection C :- {"cId" : 0 , "data" : "A"}, {"cId" : 1 , "data" : "B"} .

Comment: i am asking that how to create that "aId" & "bId" & "cId" auto increment id for three collections. Thanks in advance !!!